# ggplot plot size for inline graphic knitr

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I am creating a ggplot then using knitr to create a web page with the image as an inline graphic. At the moment I use 'out.width' to increase the size of the graphic in knitr, as the size produced by ggplot is too small.

An example of what I mean is [here](http://rpubs.com/d11/test1). The first map is the size produced by ggplot, the second at 800px is increased using out.width - as you'll see the quality of the image deteriorates.

Is there a way to create a bigger output from ggplot? This feels like a really basic question but I can't find an answer, maybe I have been using the wrogn search terms. Could not find anything in the Hadley Wickham ggplot2 book either.

Thanks

Comment: I have no check mark next to your answer that enables me to accept it, but that works perfectly thank you

Comment: Could this answer be reformatted to the proper stackoverflow etiquette?